# Text out of margin in latex multicols environment

Tags: xetex, environments, margins

I'm setting the margin configurations for multiple environments. For instances `firstenvironment` sets the margins using `\setlength`, then I make use of the multicols package inside the new environment. The problem is that the text doesn't seem to respect the **bottom margin** in the first page where the environment is just being used, but the text in the next pages do respect the margins. The same happens when I create a second environment with its own margin configurations. Not sure why the margins are not activated immediately when the environment begins. Any suggestions would be welcome, thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe} % show the frame margins
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{firstenvironment}{
    \setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
    \setlength{\voffset}{0mm}
    \setlength{\headsep}{20pt}
    \setlength{\headheight}{4em}
    \setlength{\textheight}{6in}
    \setlength{\footskip}{10mm}}{}

\newenvironment{secondenvironment}{
    \setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
    \setlength{\voffset}{0mm}
    \setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
    \setlength{\headheight}{2em}
    \setlength{\textheight}{5in}
    \setlength{\footskip}{20mm}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{firstenvironment}
\setlength\columnsep{30pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
        {\Large\bf 1ST LIPSUM}\\
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{firstenvironment}

\newpage

\begin{secondenvironment}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    {\Large\bf 2ND LIPSUM}\\
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{secondenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: What is purposes of `firstenvironment` and `secondenvironment`? If you not use them in document, `multicolumns` work fine. These environment (as far as I see) only prevent that `multicols` can be spread over more pages.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `\bf` in latex (it is not defined by default, just in some classes fro compatibility with documents from before 1994)

Comment: while it is possible to change the page dimensions after a forced page break (see lscape package landscape environment or geometry package `\newgeometry`) you need to do a lot more than this and reset all the internal parameters, just setting `\textheight` for example  won't change the internal `\vsize` that is the size tex will actually use for page breaking. It isn't clear what you want these environments to do but perhaps `\newgeometry` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out how to fix it. I made use of the package **changepage**. The idea is to include in the parameters of this command, the differences between the **new margins** and **old margins**. There is no need to use environments to set pages with different margins (which considers header, footer and margin notes), but to keep the same structure of the original post, I provide a solution that can be easily compared with.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{calc}

\newenvironment{firstenvironment}{}{}
\newenvironment{secondenvironment}{}{}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\textheight}{7in}
\setlength{\headsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{4em}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}

\begin{firstenvironment}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        {\Large 1ST LIPSUM}\\
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{firstenvironment}

\newpage
\changepage{-2in}{}{}{}{}{}{2em-4em}{5pt-20pt}{20mm-10mm}
%\changepage{textheight}{textwidth}{evensidemargin}{oddsidemargin}{columnsep}{topmargin}{headheight}{headsep}{footskip}

\begin{secondenvironment}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        {\Large 2ND LIPSUM}\\
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{secondenvironment}

\restoregeometry

\begin{firstenvironment}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        {\Large 3rd LIPSUM}\\
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{firstenvironment}

\end{document}
```

- The command `\changepage` considers the following parameters:
  `\changepage{textheight}{textwidth}{evensidemargin}{oddsidemargin}{columnsep}{topmargin}{headheight}{headsep}{footskip}`
- The margins that are left in blank under the `\changepage` command consider the default margins of the **article** class. If you want to restore the margins after setting a new one, just use the command `\restoregeometry`

[image]